# Finding the limit of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I could just prove that the sequence is bounded but couldn't find the exact limit.

Comment: You just need the existence. BTW, the exact limit is $\dfrac{\pi ^2}{6}$.

Comment: But how to prove that the limit is nearly 2

Comment: Here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: See also Robin Chapman's notes about this problem here: http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf

Comment: Please state exactly what you are trying to do: (a) prove the existence of limit; (b) show it's "nearly 2" (?); (c) find its exact value.

Answer (score 2):

The series is (obviously) $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. And thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{pi^2}{6}$. See also the hyperharmonic/p-series for more information. This problem is called Basel problem. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) for a detailed proof.